# Gulp + Bower - Como importar os componentes instalados pelo Bower para meu projeto final

Tags: javascript, less, bower, gulp, gulpjs

Estou começando a gerenciar meus componentes com Bower e estou com uma dúvida:

Utilizo o Gulp para executar tarefas como compilar meus arquivos less, concatenar javascripts, só que como os componentes do Bower ficam dentro do **bower_components** não sei como posso organizar o gulpfile.js do meu próprio projeto para importar os arquivos que os componentes usam sem precisar de muito trabalho manual.

Existe algum paradigma de organização / importação de tais componentes?

Espero ter sido claro. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não utilizo Bower, mas o Gulp te permite designar mais de um *path* para buscar os arquivos onde tarefas serão executadas, logo, você poderia fazer algo como:

```
// gulpfile.js
// ...

gulp.task('minha-task', function() {
    return gulp.src(['path/meus/scripts/*.js', 'path/bower_components/**/*.js'])
        .minhasTasks() //...
});
```

A linha:

```
return gulp.src(['path/meus/scripts/*.js', 'path/bower_components/**/*.js'])
```

chama um array (neste caso, com 2 *paths*) e vai rodar sua task em qualquer arquivo achado dentro desses dois locais.

Note que eu adicionei `**` no *path* onde ficariam os componentes importados com o Bower, porque desta forma mesmo que eles estejam divididos por subpastas, o Gulp ainda conseguiria identificá-los e rodar os seus arquivos `.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma tarefa para copiar determinado arquivo para o destino desejado. No caso de JS, também pode utilizar o gulp-concat para concatenar todos os arquivos JS e no projeto final ter apenas um arquivo.js com tudo concatenado e minificado.